# How to set environment variables on React with custom webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

My React app isn't run by create-react-app, but a custom Webpack config.

I"ve installed `dotenv` / `dotenv-expand` / and also `dotenv-webpack`.

I have `.env` / `.env.development` files with `API_URL` variable in it.

On my url file,

```
const { API_URL } = process.env
```

and use this `API_URL` to fetch data.

But on this file, when I `console.log(process.env)`, it is empty.

I also have tried to update `webpack.config.js` file with

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
```

and

```
new Dotenv()
```

in plugins array.

But still doesn't work.

I also tried having variable name `REACT_APP_API_URL` but was same result.

Could anyone help me to set the env vars?

Thank you.

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge')

const modeConfig = env => require(`./build-utils/webpack.${env}`)(env)
const presetConfig = require('./build-utils/loadPresets')

module.exports = ({ mode, presets } = { mode: 'production', presets: [] }) => {
  console.log('mode', mode, 'presets', presets)
  return webpackMerge(
    {
      mode,
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/,
            use: {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: 'assets/[name].[ext]',
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      node: {
        fs: 'empty'
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
      },
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].lazy-chunk.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: mode === 'development' ? '/' : './'
      },
      devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
      },
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: './build-utils/template.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
        new Dotenv()
      ]
    },
    modeConfig(mode),
    presetConfig({ mode, presets })
  )
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example of your webpack config? 

Just to clarify are you trying to access your env variable in another JS file and not your webpack config?

Comment: Yes, trying to access env var in another JS file not in webpack config.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to access the `env` values in your JS files, you typically need to have the `dotenv` plugin.

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge')

require('dotenv').config() // may need to set path to your .env file if it isn't at the root at the project

const modeConfig = env => require(`./build-utils/webpack.${env}`)(env)
const presetConfig = require('./build-utils/loadPresets')

module.exports = ({ mode, presets } = { mode: 'production', presets: [] }) => {
  return webpackMerge(
      ...
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: './build-utils/template.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
           'process.env': {
               NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
               SOME_VALUE: JSON.stringify(process.env.SOME_VALUE),
               ...
            }
        })
      ]
    },
    ...
  )
}
```

NOTE: With this implementation you won't be able to do 
`const { API_URL } = process.env` because `DefinePlugin` does a search and replace of the JavaScript where it will look up any references to `process.env.API_URL` and replace it with whatever that value is. Therefore `API_URL` won't exist on `porcess.env`, so to use it just do `process.env.API_URL`

You could also use `dotenv-webpack`, I think you were close to getting it to work.

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge')

const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

const modeConfig = env => require(`./build-utils/webpack.${env}`)(env)
const presetConfig = require('./build-utils/loadPresets')

module.exports = ({ mode, presets } = { mode: 'production', presets: [] }) => {
  return webpackMerge(
      ...
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: './build-utils/template.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
        new Dotenv({
           path: envPath
        })
      ]
    },
    ...
  )
}
```

If you need more help please share more details in by creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If I add that require line, gets an error saying Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Comment: You'll need to require `fs`. i.e `const fs = require('fs');` `fs` is the File System module in Node

Comment: Do I need to pass that `fs` to anywhere?

Comment: You shouldn't need to!

Comment: Still having the same error. Which file would you like to check? I can update the file here

Comment: Could you add your webpack config?

Also are you running webpack-devserver by any chance? If so you'll have to restart everything to see any changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207216/discussion-between-doobean-and-sherman-hui).

Comment: I learned from your answer, at least i got the idea and there were docs for both plugins which helped me. ;)